# Button getting hidden

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, popup, css-grid

how can I do so that the button is not hidden when resizing the modal?

I'm having trouble solving this problem can someone help me?

I believe it must be simple to solve, I just couldn't find the solution yet

below is the JSX code (React) and CSS code

if you look at the image you will be better able to understand the problem[image]

JSX (React) code below:

```
<Modal open={this.props.open} visible={this.props.visible}>
        <div class={style.Container}>
          <div class={style.Header}>
            <div class={style.Title}>{data.subject}</div>
            <div
              class={style.Buttons2}
              onClick={(event) => this.props.visible(false)}
            >
              <MdBackspace size="24px" color="#FFF" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} class={style.Wrapper}>
            <div class={style.Message}>
              {ReactHtmlParser(this.state.message)}
            </div>
            <div class={style.Editor}>
              <ReactQuill
                value={this.state.content}
                onChange={this.handleType}
              />
            </div>
            <div class={style.Controls}>
              <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileSelected} />
              {this.state.buttonState ? (
                <button class={style.SendButton} type="submit">
                  Enviar
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button class={style.ButtonDisabled} disabled>
                  Enviar
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
```

CSS code below:

```
.Container {
  width: 720px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #405c77;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #405c77;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Title {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.Wrapper {
  /* flex: 1 1 100%; */
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-rows: 60% 30% 40px; */
  grid-template-rows: minmax(5px, 1fr);
}

.Message {
  /* height: 100%; */
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.111);
}

.Editor {
  height: calc(30% - 40px);
  /* height: 100%; */
  margin: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.Buttons2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.SendButton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(64, 92, 119, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.SendButton:hover {
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(64, 92, 119, 0.999);
}

.ButtonDisabled {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.Controls {
  /* height: 40px; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Controls input {
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: What is your css style.Controls ?

Comment: @OmarSy 
is a div that encapsulates the button and an input just

Comment: Could you put this in codesandbox?

Comment: @ShingaiMunyuki I Can not put this code in SandBox sorry, can You help me just seeing the code I put here? look at the image please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting your button inside the Editor div?

```
    <div class={style.Editor}>
          <ReactQuill
            value={this.state.content}
            onChange={this.handleType}
          />
       <div class={style.Controls}>
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileSelected} />
          {this.state.buttonState ? (
            <button class={style.SendButton} type="submit">
              Enviar
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button class={style.ButtonDisabled} disabled>
              Enviar
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        </div>
```

Its difficult without being able to inspect it properly

Comment: the problem still persists I will try it with another way

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{

position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:5;

}
```

Comment: where I must put it?

Comment: in your button style

Comment: Your answer is currently marked as low quality and faces deletion. Please make sure your answer contains an explanation aside from any code.